# How do I remotely unlock Google Device Manager remote lock when I know the password?

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, android-device-manager

Is there an option to remotely unlock the online Android Device Manager's lock feature if I have the password?

### I have read "How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?" but I do not have my phone, it was stolen. Also, I have the Google Device Manager password I used to lock my Samsung Active S5 after it was stolen.

If anyone wants to help me find it I would be very grateful. 
I installed the GDM before it was stolen and did not know about all it's features. I locked it because of the data overages. I wish I had not done because it was being tracked by the google maps Location History feature and was tracking every movement until I locked it and shut off the data via my provider. I turned back on the data but the provider said that the phone would have to be manually restarted for the data to start working. So I am hoping that if I unlock it they will start using it again and I can alert the police or get it myself.

I am trying to track the phone before I goto the police. I read the police very rarely recover a phone and this has my life on it and was not backed up properly I just got it and I traded in my old phone. I am a screwed idiot big time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method for unlocking in google device manager, but, you could try setting the password to password, and setting the text as, 'the password is password'.

However, if you can't contact the phone, it is probable that they have wiped it an set up their own google account.

There isn't much you can do, except, tell the police your IMEI number, they probably have a database of lost and stolen phones.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I used "the password is password" suggestion, I'll let you know if we get my phone back.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings > Lock Screen > Security. Make sure everything is clear and then there are other security settings, it will allow you there to deactivate.